# Invalid pointer error whily running python in C++ using pybind11 and pytorch

Tags: python, c++, c++11, pytorch, pybind11

While running the following python code in C++ using pybind11, pytorch 1.6.0, I get "Invalid Pointer" error. In python, the code runs successfully without any error. Whats the reason? How can I solve this problem?

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torchvision
import eval_widerface
import torchvision_model

def resize(image, size):
    image = F.interpolate(image.unsqueeze(0), size=size, mode="nearest").squeeze(0)
    return image    

# define constants
model_path = '/path/to/model.pt'
image_path = '/path/to/image_pad.jpg'
scale = 1.0 #Image resize scale (2 for half size)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

MIN_SCORE = 0.9
image_bgr = cv2.imread(image_path)
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)#skimage.io.imread(args.image_path)
cv2.imshow("input image",image_bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# load pre-trained model
return_layers = {'layer2':1,'layer3':2,'layer4':3}
RetinaFace = torchvision_model.create_retinaface(return_layers)

print('RetinaFace.state_dict().')
retina_dict = RetinaFace.state_dict()
```

the following function generates error.

```
def create_retinaface(return_layers,backbone_name='resnet50',anchors_num=3,pretrained=True):
    print('In create_retinaface.')
    print(resnet.__dict__)
    backbone = resnet.__dict__[backbone_name](pretrained=pretrained)
    print('backbone.')
    # freeze layer1
    for name, parameter in backbone.named_parameters():
        print('freeze layer 1.');
        # if 'layer2' not in name and 'layer3' not in name and 'layer4' not in name:
        #     parameter.requires_grad_(False)
        if name == 'conv1.weight':
            # print('freeze first conv layer...')
            parameter.requires_grad_(False)
model = RetinaFace(backbone,return_layers,anchor_nums=3)

return model
```

The statement `backbone = resnet.__dict__ [backbone_name](pretrained=pretrained)` generated error that looks like

```
*** Error in `./p': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f4461866db0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7f3e4)[0x7f44736b43e4]
/usr/local/lib64/libopencv_gapi.so.4.1(_ZNSt10_HashtableISsSsSaISsENSt8__detail9_IdentityESt8equal_toISsESt4hashISsENS1_18_Mod_range_hashingENS1_20_Default_ranged_hashENS1_20_Prime_rehash_policyENS1_17_Hashtable_traitsILb1ELb1ELb1EEEE21_M_insert_unique_nodeEmmPNS1_10_Hash_nodeISsLb1EEE+0xc9)[0x7f4483dee1a9]
/home/20face/.virtualenvs/torch/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so(+0x4403b5)[0x7f4460bb73b5]
/home/20face/.virtualenvs/torch/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so(+0x44570a)[0x7f4460bbc70a]
/home/20face/.virtualenvs/torch/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so(+0x275b20)[0x7f44609ecb20]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyCFunction_FastCallDict+0x147)[0x7f4474307167]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1507df)[0x7f44743727df]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3a7)[0x7f44743670f7]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1505ca)[0x7f44743725ca]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x150903)[0x7f4474372903]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3a7)[0x7f44743670f7]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x14fb69)[0x7f4474371b69]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x24f)[0x7f44743739ff]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x10e)[0x7f44742ca1de]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_Call_Prepend+0x61)[0x7f44742ca2f1]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f44742c9f63]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0xfa7e5)[0x7f447431c7e5]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0xf71e2)[0x7f44743191e2]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f44742c9f63]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x2067)[0x7f4474368db7]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x24f)[0x7f4474372c9f]
```

Comment: Please make sure to add the c++ tag to questions related to C++. I replaced it with a tag that doesn't seem appropriate instead.

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing the error because it assumes `__dict__` has a `backbone_name` element:

```
backbone = resnet.__dict__[backbone_name](pretrained=pretrained)
```

When that isn't the case, it basically tries to access invalid memory. Check `__dict__` first with an `if` statement or make sure that it has the `backbone_name` element before trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It has the 'backbone_name' element and its value is 'resnet50'. It works in python and when I print(resnet.__dict__[backbone_name](pretrained=True)) in python, it prints the architecture of resent50. It creates problem when I embed python in C++.

Comment: Hi,@Fisa, I also met this problem, even the crashed funtion call stack is the same. Could you please give some more information about this question? How did you solve it at last? 
 My case is: a C++ function calls the Python script through PyImport_ImportModule and PyEval_CallObject; the Python function has a sentence "net = jit.load('mymodels.jit')", which crashes here.